# sort a list of tuples in a specific way

Tags: python, list, sorting, key, tuples

I am trying to sort a list (in which elements are tuples) in decreasing order in accordance with sum of 2 integers that each tuple contain

For example:

```
lst  = [('firstWord', 4, 3), ('secondWord', 9, 3), ('thirdWord', 2, 6)]
```

I need to sort with parameters  4+3 = 7, 9+3 = 12, 2+6 = 8, so the returned list will be

```
lst  = [('secondWord', 9, 3), ('thirdWord', 2, 6), ('firstWord', 4, 3)]
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: thank you for advice! i am new in this society so thank you for a tip.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lambda to add the last two elements, and then negate it so you get a descending order:

```
>>> lst = [('firstWord', 4, 3), ('secondWord', 9, 3), ('thirdWord', 2, 6)]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: -1 * (x[1] + x[2]))
[('secondWord', 9, 3), ('thirdWord', 2, 6), ('firstWord', 4, 3)]
```